# How to set HTTP 201 as a default status for ActionController::API#create in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

As title states, I wonder is it possible to globally set `status :created` for all Ruby on Rails API controllers' create action `ActionController::API#create` when rendering the response using Views, for example with `jbuilder` gem.

When using the gem, there's no need to explicitly call the `render` method, all I need is my controllers' create action

```
def create
  @tv_show = current_user.tv_shows.build(tv_show_params)
  @tv_show.validate
  render_unprocessable_entity(@tv_show.errors.messages) and return if @tv_show.errors.present?

  @tv_show.save
end
```

and the corresponding view file, which in this case is `app/views/tv_shows/create.json.jbuilder`.

Rails seems to render `status :ok` by default anytime it responds with its view.

What I've tried, trying to "guess" the Rails syntax:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  status: :created, only: :create
end
```

Unfortunately, with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

In your `ApplicationController`

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  after_action :set_code_on_create, only: [:create]

  private
    def set_code_on_create
      response.status = 201 if response.status == 200
    end
end
```

Since your adding `:set_code_on_create` in `ApplicationController`, this will take effect globally to all controllers.

If you don't want to change the status of `201` to `#create` action of any controller(say `Articles Controller`), then in `ArticlesController` you can skip this:

```rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  skip_after_action :set_code_on_create, only: [:create]
end
```

---

**EDIT 1:** Since above will override other response codes like `401`(or `422` or others), which is not desirable, so included `if response.status == 200` to just override if response status is `:ok`

Comment: Consider that during the `create` execution I set other status codes, such as `:unprocessable_entity` in the `render_unprocessable_entity`. Does your approach override it? I think it does, and it is not desired behavior.

Comment: Ah, this is a valid point, I've updated the answer, I added `if response.status == 200` i.e. only change response code to `201` if jbuilder/rails sends `200`, if there is some error it will just show that error.

Comment: And what about skipping the `if` part and using `before_action` instead of the `after_action` callback? This way any overrides within the action body will take precedence.